# How can I exhaust /dev/urandom for testing?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, random, entropy

I recently had a bug where I didn't properly handle when the entropy on my linux server got too low and a read of /dev/urandom returned less than the number of bytes expected.

How can I recreate this with a test?  Is there a way to lower the entropy on a system or to reliably empty /dev/urandom?

I'd like to be able to have a regression test that will verify my fix.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You can deplete the entropy by repeatedly reading urandom.  You can read the current entropy level in `/proc/sys/kernel/random/`

Answer (score 8):

According to [random(4)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html) man page,

```
read from the /dev/urandom device will not block
```

You should read  a lot of bytes from `/dev/random` (without any `u`) if you want it to block. (How many is hardware and system dependent).

So you cannot "exaust" `/dev/urandom`, since

> ```
>  A read from the /dev/urandom device will not block waiting for 
>  more entropy. As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in 
>  the entropy pool, the returned values are theoretically vulnerable 
>  to a cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver.
> ```

I believe you should use `/dev/random` which indeed can be exhausted, by blocking.
But you should not read more than about 256 bits from it.