# AH01990: PRNG still contains insufficient entropy

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, random

I have a problem with my apache server running on Linux Ubuntu. For some reason I have the following warning in the log file: **AH01990: PRNG still contains insufficient entropy!**. Sometimes I can access the website but most of the time I get the following warning. I tried to google this issue but I still couldn't solve this problem. It seems it is related to /dev/urandom. When I restart apache, the website is accessible for couple minutes but after that I get this error.
I tried adding 
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512 and 
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512 to the apache2.conf
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that help your RNG to gain enough entropy: [clrngd](http://freecode.com/projects/clrngd), [rng-tools](https://www.howtoforge.com/helping-the-random-number-generator-to-gain-enough-entropy-with-rng-tools-debian-lenny), [haveged](https://linux.die.net/man/8/haveged) and [egd](http://egd.sourceforge.net/), but in properly configured Linux environment the /dev/**u**random exhaustion should be [an unlikely event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017454/6948900), so I would investigate this first.

I would check my kernel configuration for everything related to RNG and probably there are some vital options disabled.

Then, I would double- and triple-check my Apache configuration. Though, you're saying you enabled `SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512`, something still might override it with /dev/random (without **u**, which is kind of hi-quality random source and it is more likely to exhaust fast) or something like that.

Then, I would check if my random-consumption is sane. I probably can't explain it well, but the idea is: your software might generate certificates more often then it really needs them. It's like if you have two options: generate SSL cert for server and use it for all connections OR generate a new certificate for every connection. So the second option is kind of wrong and might lead to periodic RNG depletion.

Also, there is [a common problem with entropy in virtualization containers](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/challenges-with-randomness-in-multi-tenant-linux-container-platforms).

Comment: When I restart apache server, it says there is about 3150 entropy. However, after couple minutes there is about 3170 but the website stops working and I get the following error in the log file: AH01990: PRNG still contains insufficient entropy!. It seems that entropy is enough but for reason the website works just for couple minutes after I restart the server.

Comment: Well it really seems that everything is OK with random source, must be apache then. One last guess... If you check entropy amount as root user and apache runs under another user/group, does your apache [have enough permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/391386/why-is-dev-urandom-only-readable-by-root-since-ubuntu-12-04-and-how-can-i-fix) to access /dev/urandom? Or maybe try to update/downgrade apache if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`
`sudo pip install cryptography --upgrade`
I was having the same problem and finally today was able to fix it using this https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3282.

Must've been something with the cryptography library that was causing this error.
I have apache with flask running on an Amazon EC2 instance.